# Simplenews newsletter producing undecoded base64 email

Tags: emails, files

I have a client site that's running Simplenews with Mime Mail and SMTP Authentication Support. Everything works fine except when my client wants to include a link to a YouTube video (and just to be clear, this just a link to the video, not an attempt to embed a video in the newsletter). Here is an excerpt of the resulting newsletter email:

> PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBIVE1MIDQuMCBUcmFuc2l0aW9uYWwvL0VOIiAiaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvVFIvUkVDLWh0bWw0MC9sb29zZS5kdGQiPgo8aHRtbD4KPGhlYWQ+PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0L2h0bWw7nIGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTgiPjwvaGVhZD4KPGJvZHkgaWQ9Im1pbWVtYWlsLWJvZHkiIHN0eWxlPSJi

. . . and so on. No other links cause this to occur. When I look at the email source, the plain text version is fine. This only happens to the HTML version. I am thoroughly stumped. Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Looks like a PGP/GPG-encoded mail.

Comment: That's interesting. Any idea why a YouTube link would invoke PGP/GPG encoding?

Comment: It just looks like it. I wouldn't even know how this could happen if you don't have encryption keys set up (which I guess you don't have on a server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in the SMTP Authentication Module. It uses uses 8bit encoding in the Content-Transfer-Encoding header for the base64 encoded body. I applied this patch with success:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1741082#comment-9121815